# Entity Framework 6 Runtime Error: "given key was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-6

I am writing an ASP.Net app using EF6 code-first and table per hierarchy

I get this error whenever I attempt to do anything meaningful with my dbcontext (such as a query, update, etc.):

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException",
  "StackTrace": "  at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.CreateCommandDefinition(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()\r\n  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n  at SealingServer.Controllers.PdfsController.<PostPdf>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Users\thoma_000\Documents\All Code\SealingServer\SealingServer\Controllers\PdfsController.cs:line 93\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n  at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The given key was not present in the dictionary.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException",
    "StackTrace": "  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.MemberDomainMap.GetDomainInternal(MemberPath path)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.QueryRewriting.FragmentQueryKB.CreateIsOfTypeCondition(MemberPath currentPath, IEnumerable`1 derivedTypes, MemberDomainMap domainMap)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.QueryRewriting.FragmentQueryKB.CreateVariableConstraintsRecursion(EdmType edmType, MemberPath currentPath, MemberDomainMap domainMap, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.QueryRewriting.FragmentQueryKB.CreateVariableConstraintsRecursion(EdmType edmType, MemberPath currentPath, MemberDomainMap domainMap, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewgenContext..ctor(ViewTarget viewTarget, EntitySetBase extent, IList`1 extentCells, CqlIdentifiers identifiers, ConfigViewGenerator config, MemberDomainMap queryDomainMap, MemberDomainMap updateDomainMap, EntityContainerMapping entityContainerMapping)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.CreateViewgenContext(EntitySetBase extent, ViewTarget viewTarget, CqlIdentifiers identifiers)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateDirectionalViewsForExtent(ViewTarget viewTarget, EntitySetBase extent, CqlIdentifiers identifiers, KeyToListMap`2 views)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateDirectionalViews(ViewTarget viewTarget, CqlIdentifiers identifiers, KeyToListMap`2 views)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateAllBidirectionalViews(KeyToListMap`2 views, CqlIdentifiers identifiers)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewgenGatekeeper.GenerateViewsFromCells(List`1 cells, ConfigViewGenerator config, CqlIdentifiers identifiers, EntityContainerMapping containerMapping)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedGenerateViews(EntityContainerMapping entityContainerMap, Dictionary`2 resultDictionary)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedGetGeneratedViews(EntityContainer container)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent, MetadataWorkspace workspace, StorageMappingItemCollection storageMappingItemCollection)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ExpandView(ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(Node scanTableNode, ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ScanTableOp op, Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(FilterOp op, Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.VisitScalarOpDefault(ScalarOp op, Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.VisitNavPropertyOp(PropertyOp op, Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(PropertyOp op, Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.VisitScalarOpDefault(ScalarOp op, Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(PlanCompiler planCompilerState, StructuredTypeInfo& typeInfo, Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)\r\n  at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)"
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I started over with a fresh database and I get the same result for any entity. This leads me to believe it has to do with my DbContext. It looks like this:

```
public class SealingServerContext : DbContext
    {
        public SealingServerContext() : base("name=TFMContext")
        {
            this.Database.Log = Console.Write;
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }
    public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ReviewerRole> ReviewerRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AnnotationTemplate> AnnotationTemplates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PaperItem> PaperItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PaperRaster> PaperRasters { get; set; }

    public DbSet<EngineerRole> EngineerRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Seal> Seals { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Signature> Signatures { get; set; }


    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobFile> JobFiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pdf> Pdfs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PdfPage> PdfPages { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AnnotationTemplate>()
            .HasKey(annotationTemplate => annotationTemplate.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<JobFile>()
            .HasKey(pdf => pdf.ID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Pdf>()
            .HasKey(pdf => pdf.ID)
            .HasMany(pdf => pdf.PdfPages)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(pdfPage => pdfPage.Pdf_ID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
            .HasKey(job => job.ID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
            .HasMany(job => job.Files)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(jobFile => jobFile.Job_ID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
            .HasMany(job => job.Regions)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(region => region.Job_ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>()
            .HasKey(organization => organization.ID)
            .HasMany(org => org.Users)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(user => user.Organization_ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PaperItem>()
            .HasKey(paperItem => paperItem.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PaperRaster>()
            .HasKey(paperRaster => paperRaster.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Files.PdfPage>()
            .HasKey(pdfPage => pdfPage.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Region>()
            .HasKey(region => region.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
            .HasKey(role => role.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EngineerRole>()
            .HasKey(role => role.ID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EngineerRole>()
            .HasMany(engineerRole => engineerRole.Seals)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(seal => seal.EngineerRole_ID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EngineerRole>()
            .HasMany(engineerRole => engineerRole.Signatures)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(signature => signature.EngineerRole_ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EngineerAdminRole>()
            .HasKey(role => role.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ReviewerAdminRole>()
            .HasKey(role => role.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ReviewerRole>()
            .HasKey(reviewerRole => reviewerRole.ID)
            .HasMany(reviewerRole => reviewerRole.AnnotationTemplates)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(annotation => annotation.ReviewerRole_ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Seal>()
            .HasKey(seal => seal.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Signature>()
            .HasKey(signature => signature.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasKey(user => user.ID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(user => user.Roles)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(role => role.User_ID);
    }
}
```

**Edit2**

I've been commenting things out and doing db migrations and have narrowed it down to this inheritance hierarchy:

```
[KnownType(typeof(PaperRaster))]
public class PaperItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public PointF PdfPosition { get; set; }

    public string ItemType { get; set; }

    public virtual void Move(PointF coordinatesTranslation)
    {
    }

    protected PaperItem(string paperItemType, PointF pdfPosition)
    {
        ItemType = paperItemType;
        PdfPosition = pdfPosition;
    }

    public virtual PaperItem DeepCopy()
    {
        return new PaperItem("PaperItem", new PointF());
    }


    public virtual string ToJson()
    {
        //turn all of my properties into Json
        return "";
    }
}
```

and its child class:

```
public class PaperRaster : PaperItem
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string CrossOrigin { get; set; }
    public Matrix Matrix { get; set; }

    public PaperRaster(string source, string crossOrigin, Matrix matrix, PointF pdfPosition)
        : base("Raster", pdfPosition)
    {
        this.Source = source;
        this.CrossOrigin = crossOrigin;
        this.Matrix = matrix;
    }

    public PaperRaster(string json) : base("Raster", new PointF())
    {
        JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);

        JToken type = array[0];
        JToken properties = array[1];
        JToken position = array[2]["pdfPosition"];


        if (type.ToString() != "Raster")
        {
            throw new Exception("Not a PaperRaster");
        }

        var matrix = properties["matrix"];
        this.Matrix = new Matrix(float.Parse(matrix[0].ToString()), float.Parse(matrix[1].ToString()),
            float.Parse(matrix[2].ToString()), float.Parse(matrix[3].ToString()),
            float.Parse(matrix[4].ToString()), float.Parse(matrix[5].ToString()));

        // Custom encoded properties

        // Bottom left point of annotation (that's how iTextSharp inserts it)

        var x = position["x"].ToString();
        var y = position["y"].ToString();

        this.PdfPosition = new PointF()
        {
            X = float.Parse(x),
            Y = float.Parse(y)
        };
    }

    public override void Move(PointF coordinatesTranslation)
    {
        this.Matrix.Translate(coordinatesTranslation.X, coordinatesTranslation.Y);
    }

    public override PaperItem DeepCopy()
    {
        return new PaperRaster(this.Source, this.CrossOrigin, this.Matrix, this.PdfPosition);
    }

    public override string ToJson()
    {
        //turn all of my properties into Json
        return "";
    }
}
```

If I comment out the child class and do a db migration. Everything goes back to working. What in this inheritance hierarchy causes EF to incorrectly generate the tables

*Other Notes*

Strange sidenote, doing this works:

```
var result = context.dbset.Single(x => x.ID == 10000);
```

However using `Find` like so:

```
var result = context.dbset.Find(10000);
```

causes the error above.

Comment: Cab you show the entities and query generating that error?

Comment: @ESG It occurs on every entity and every query so It leads me to believe that it has something to do with the dbcontext

Comment: @ESG All entities cause the error

Comment: What about your entities?

Comment: @ESG Any query, create, or update on them from the dbcontext

Comment: Hi jth41, can you please confirm, are you connecting to a local instance of SQL Server (Express, etc), or LocalDB or another type of database?  Kind regards.

Comment: @StefanZvonar I am pointed at an Azure Sql Server

Answer (score 1):

I have figure it out the problem for me. It was related to a **not mapped property** inside the derived entity (and could also occurs when the entire **derived class is not mapped**). I described it better in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36756830/890890) answer.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is because you don't have a primary key, which precludes the use of `Find` as it works only on the primary key.

You can set the primary key implicitly by adding a column that conforms to the naming convention:

```
Dog
===
Id || DogId
```

Note you specified `ID`, so the casing is wrong.

You can also set the key explicitly by decorating the property with `[Key]` as well.

Comment: Can confirm all of the models have their Primary Keys explicitly declared in the fluent statements in the DbContext (See edits to the question)